# When are selection listeners register in a view?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, event-listener

I have a `View` in my RCP application that draws some things and it's created when the user clicks a certain `Toolbar` action. The `View` implments the `ISelectionProvider` and when some objects in the view are clicked their properties are shown in the property view.

The problem is when I programmatically show the `view` through `getActivePage.showView("viewid")` in the `run()` method of the action it seems that no `listeners` are registered so nothing is shown in the properties view.

As soons as a hide the view by pressing some other `view` to appear and then I open it again the listeners are registered and the properties are shown.

So in what method are these `listeners` registered that is not called with the `showView` command?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the selection is announced if the view has focus, try setting the focus programmatically before showing it.

Comment: same behavior... register are not registered

Comment: You are using the word 'registered' which is confusing the issue somewhat. Are you actually saying that the view isn't registering itself as a selection provider? I doubt that can be the case.

Comment: Also, i'm sure you've tried things in different orders, but for me, the first view that would normally provide properties always fails to do so, it's not because the listeners aren't there it's because it's sending the wrong adapter type across, and it will start working if I click on a different view and and back again. I have never managed to get an answer as to why it does that.

Answer (score 0):

It's triggered when the part is activated. Try

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView("myViewId", null, IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE)
```

Comment: it produces tha same behavior